# LINQ to Entities not recognizing method

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
    public IList<Folder> GetArchivedFolders(int userId)
    {
        return _db.Folders.Where(f => f.IsArchived).Where(s =>
            IsTopLevelArchivedFolder(s.FolderId)
            ).ToList();
    }
    private bool IsTopLevelArchivedFolder(int folderId)
    {
        var folder = GetFolder(folderId);
        if (folder.ParentFolderIdWhileArchived > 0)
        {
            if (folder.ParentFolderId != null && !GetFolder((int) folder.ParentFolderId).IsArchived)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This isn't working though because it seems EF can't run my code.

I tried this:

```
    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Folder, bool>> IsTopLevelArchivedFolder()
    {
        var folder = this;
        if (folder.ParentFolderIdWhileArchived > 0)
        {
            if (folder.ParentFolderId != null && !GetFolder((int) folder.ParentFolderId).IsArchived)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but `this` is resolving to the container class, not a `Folder` object.  Is there any way I can run my code in this query?

**UPDATE:**

the following code:

```
    public IList<Folder> GetArchivedFolders(int userId)
    {

        return _db.Folders.
            Where(f => f.IsArchived).
            Where(s => IsTopLevelArchivedFolder(s)).
            ToList();
    }
    public bool IsTopLevelArchivedFolder(Folder folder)
    {
        return (folder.ParentFolderIdWhileArchived > 0) &&
           (folder.ParentFolderId != null && !folder.IsArchived);
    }
```

results in this:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   IsTopLevelArchivedFolder(Nogginator.Repository.Models.Folder)' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ is telling you that it does not know how to translate your function to SQL. You can tell LINQ to execute your function in Memory by using the `.AsEnumberable()` method on your `IQueryable`:

```
public IList<Folder> GetArchivedFolders(int userId)
{
    return _db.Folders.Where(f => f.IsArchived)
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(s => IsTopLevelArchivedFolder(s.FolderId))
                      .ToList();
}
```